# fatal error: Index out of range when using UITableView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to delete items from an array using a UITableView, however the UITableView has multiple sections and I keep getting the following error when deleting the cell

> fatal error: Index out of range

For:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Delete the row from the data source
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

            if let table = self.table {

            self.sectionItems.remove(at: [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section][(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])

            table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.left )

            }

    }
}
```

Here's how I am populating the UITableView

```
let sections = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
var sectionItems = [ [String](), [String](), [String](), [String]() ]


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return sections.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    return (self.sectionItems[section] as AnyObject).count

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return sections[section]

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = self.sectionItems[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section][(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    return cell

}
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong ?

I tried changing

```
  table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.left )
```

to

```
  table.deleteRows(at: [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section][(indexPath as NSIndexPath)]
```

But I get the error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]' with an index of type
>   'NSIndexPath'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `remove` on the wrong array.  You are calling it on your `sectionItems` array, not the array that is contained in the `sectionItems` array.

You need to use the `indexPath.section` to retrieve the appropriate array first, then call remove:

```
self.sectionItems[indexPath.section].remove(at:indexPath.row)
```

Comment: Sorry but also how could I get the string value of the indexPath.row from the sectionItems, array within an array, that I am deleting from ?

Comment: If I wanted to create a new property say let item = Whatever self.sectionItems[indexPath.section].remove(at:indexPath.row) is

Comment: `let currentValue = self.sectionItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` and    `self.sectionItems[indexPath.section].append("New Item")`  If you just wanted to replace the value `self.sectionItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]="new value"`